# What is the probability that a random family of 4 gets wiped out by Thanos? (i.e 50 % of population being dead)

Tags: probability

I am confused about this. Do we need to consider in the factor of household distribution in the world?

The context is the movie *Avengers: Infinity War.* The important part of the question is a movie spoiler:

> At the end of the movie, Thanos gets all six infinity stones, snaps his fingers, and half of the universe dies.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: I am asking if 50% of the world population is dying then what is the probability of family of 4 dying.

Comment: @lulu The ending of *Avengers: Infinity Wars*.

Comment: That's fine for those who have seen the movie. But this is a mathematics site, not a movie fan site, hence this question is entirely unclear.

Comment: It was perfectly clear to me! :)

Comment: Why do we not factor in the household distribution? What if the question was what is the prob that 4 people killed in snapping constituted all members of a family?

Comment: I added context in the question.

Comment: @SagarKarira I created the table for the full household (from zero through four people turning to dust). Does that answer your question about the household distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider each person getting turned to dust as an independent event, which happens with probability $1/2$. Then the probability of an entire family of four getting it is $(1/2)^4 = 1/16.$

And to answer your question about the household disbribution, if half of the family *has* to get it, then you already have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

50% of all people will be wiped out. The probability that all 4 get wiped out is $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^4 = \dfrac{1}{16}$.

The full breakdown is as follows:

$$\begin{array}{c|c} \text{Num survivors in fam} & \text{Probability} \\  
\hline 0 & \binom{4}{0}\frac{1}{16} = \frac{1}{16} \\ 
1 & \binom{4}{1}\frac{1}{16} = \frac{1}{4} \\ 
2 & \binom{4}{2}\frac{1}{16} = \frac{3}{8} \\ 
3 & \binom{4}{3}\frac{1}{16} = \frac{1}{4} \\ 
4 & \binom{4}{4}\frac{1}{16} = \frac{1}{16} \\
\hline \text{Total} & 1 \end{array}$$

Comment: I was talking about the number of families on earth that has household size of 4 members. There are 12% of families out of 126 million families in USA that have 4 family members. So I thought the answer should be 12% of 1/16 since. That was my confusion.

Comment: It depends on how you word the question. If you worded it as the probability that a random family had four members and all four were wiped out, then you are correct, and it would be 12% of 1/16. If you are only looking at families with four members, then there is a 100% chance that there are only four members in the family. This is known as a conditional probability.